# How to import MXF recordings on FCP?

Tags: conversion, video-codecs

I have a problem with my MXF files when I was about to import them into FCP7. It refuse to work at all. I tried couple of plug-ins and applications but nothing worked. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

FCP does not support the MXF wrapper type by default - only MOV files will import. There's a third-party plugin which provides MXF support - [MXF4MAC](http://hamburgpromedia.com/products/mxf4mac/mxf-for-mac.php) - but I'm not sure which version you would need, and it may depend on the video format of your files.

However, if you don't have that plugin, you (probably*) do not need to transcode your input files - just re-wrapping them should suffice.

*Background:* MOV and MXF are both 'wrapper' formats, rather than video/audio formats as such. They can be 'unwrapped', which would leave you with a number of separate video and audio files, which FCP would be able to import.

Any transcode (re-encoding the video/audio essence) will cause some degradation in the image/sound quality, so should be avoided. It's also hard work to transcode video, so normally takes a long time. A re-wrap can use the same video/audio essence, but merely package it different. Think of it on the same lines as taking a RAR archive, extracting the files from it, and then putting them into a new ZIP archive - the files are completely unchanged, but the format they're delivered in has changed.

One (free) way to rewrap files would be to use command-line tool 'ffmpeg' with the 'copy' pseudo-codec specified. Without knowledge of your input file, OS version in use (the tool is included on most Linux distributions, but is available for other platforms - take your pick [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)), and ffmpeg version available, I can't give a precise command-line, but it will along the lines of:

```
ffmpeg -i MyFile.mov -c:a copy -c:v copy MyFile.mxf
```

Hope this helps - if you need any further details, we'd need some more information about the input file - the easiest way to get this information is probably [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) (again, free, available on all platforms), which can give all the internal video/audio formats in an easy to access way.

* depending on the actual video format within the MXF file - FCP supports most video formats.